# How to avoid time_t variable?

Tags: c, pointers, localtime

Newbie pointer/address optimization question.

As an exercise, I wrote this code.

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------
FUNC    : dateplusdays (date plus days)
          add/substract days to/from date
          days can be positive or negative
PARAMS  : date (int, format yyyymmdd), days (int)
RETURNS : date (int, format yyyymmdd)
REMARKS :
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
int dateplusdays(int date_1, int days) {

    int year, month, day;
    int date_2;
    struct tm time;
    time_t time_seconds;

    year = (int) floor(date_1 / 10000.0);
    month = (int) (floor(date_1 / 100.0) - year * 100);
    day = (int) (floor(date_1) - month * 100 - year * 10000);

    time.tm_sec = 0;
    time.tm_min = 0;
    time.tm_hour = 0;
    time.tm_year = year - 1900;
    time.tm_mon = month - 1;
    time.tm_mday = day;

    time_seconds = mktime(&time) + days * 86400;
    time = *localtime(&time_seconds);

    date_2 = (time.tm_year + 1900) * 10000 + (time.tm_mon + 1) * 100 + time.tm_mday;

    return date_2;

}
```

Now, for exercise purpose, I'd like to put these 2 lines in one single line, hence avoiding the variable time_seconds.

```
    time_seconds = mktime(&time) + days * 86400;
    time = *localtime(&time_seconds);
```

localtime requires the address of a time_t variable. I don't see how I could skip the step using this time_t variable.

Comment: Don't bother. It's unlikely to result in more optimised code. Just write the code as it is now (which is arguably easier to read) and let the compiler (which are pretty good nowadays) do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time = localtime((time_t[]){mktime(&time) + days * 86400});`

This is called making a "compound literal".

Comment: And is about ten times as hard to read as the original. And, most probably, not the least bit more efficient. No offence intended - after all you just correctly answered the question, but I would fire anyone who built something like that into my code...

Comment: I agree completely. I have never seen anyone do this in 15+ years of C programming. I don't even remember how I know this. Probably from another stackoverflow question.